# Send string with binary null '\0'

Tags: c, linux, udp

Hi I have programmed linux daemon who sends files in udp packets.
problem is that in string `"abc\0asdf"` it sends only `abc` not null character and `asdf` (all characters after null symbol),

there is udp client code, which send packets:

```
int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent *host;
    host= (struct hostent *) gethostbyname((char *)ip);
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1){
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);
    memset(server_addr.sin_zero,0,8);
```

and code which send buffer:

```
if (sendto(sock, buf, sizeof buf, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))==-1)
```

in serverside I need to receive binary buffer:

defining socket code:

```
int sock;
    int addr_len, bytes_read;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr , client_addr;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    //bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);
    memset(server_addr.sin_zero,0,8);
    if (bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
    sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1){
        perror("Bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

                            diep("sendto()");
```

and receive buffer (in big loop):

```
bytes_read = recvfrom(sock,buf,sizeof (buf),0,
            (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);
```

does anyone know why I didn't receive full buffer?

Comment: How are you verifying the contents of `buf`? What's the value of `bytes_read` vs the return value of `sendto`?

Comment: sender return that it sends 5000 bytes and recever return that it reads 5000 bytes, and buf size is 500 bytes.

Comment: sorry buf size is also defined 5000 bytes

Comment: @crab, so what's your question? you get exactly the amount of data you've sent

Comment: @crab, i guess, you would have a `printf("%s",buf);` statement to verify your problem. it will only read up to `\0`.

Comment: @crab: print all bytes of `buf` and see.

Comment: @Oleg but received buffer after first \0 symbol contains all \0 symbols. example I send buffer "abcd\0sdfg", and received buffer is : "abcd\0\0\0\0 ...."

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the comments, the error is most likely that you treat the received buffer as a string.

If you want to print/output the buffer, you need to convert the null character into something else first.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a for loop to print your received buffer instead of printf:

```
 for (int i=0; i<bytes_read; i++)
     printf("%c",buf[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect (formatting changed so it fits on a screen for me):

```
if (sendto(sock,
           buf,
           sizeof buf,
           0,
           (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
           sizeof(struct sockaddr))==-1)
```

You want `sizeof(server_addr)` as the length.  This will be larger than `sizeof(struct sockaddr)`.

Also, from the manpage:

> **Return Value**
>
> On success, these calls return the number of characters sent. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

You haven't accounted for the case where it returns some value less than `sizeof(buf)`.  Not sure how that can happen but it seems to be something to handle.

My comment on the overall approach is similar to what @jgauffin says.  `buf` is just bytes.  It's only a convention for C strings that `'\0'` terminates them, not a requirement.  Typically when using binary byte buffers you also track the size.  You're just assuming that all of `sizeof(buf)` will be used which doesn't make sense.  (Suggestion: Perhaps part of your `sendto` payload should include the size of the message that follows?)